# Windows Tool - SFTP to Multiple Server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, sftp

does anyone know of any tool available.
I have around 100 servers and i'd like to transfer a single file into each of them.
Is there any windows tool that does this?

Answer (score 1):

Use powershell to write a loop to call the following function

http://winscp.net/eng/docs/library#powershell

Answer (score 0):

You had a look here:

http://winscp.net/eng/index.php

You need to upload to windows servers? I you upload to a linux servers you could send it form windows to one linux server, there make a bash script that uploads the file to the other 99 servers.